# Open a Form as a SubForm

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-office

On a GUI based on forms, I try to open and close some forms in order to do calculations.

I want to do it only with Access macros (for easier maintenance by non-technical personnel).

The problem is not to open and close the forms, I've found a way to do this with:

```
Close Window
ObjectType
ObjectName
Save: With Confirmation

OpenForm
Form Name: destinationForm
Display
Filter Name
Where Condition
Data Mode
Window Mode: Standard
```

But when the forms are part of bigger form (that I called Layout for explicit reasons), this macro close the main form  and open destinationForm as a new one.

I know this behaviour is perfectly **normal**, but I haven't found marcos closing **subform** and opening other ones yet, or, even easier, changing Object Source of the subform object of my Layout form.

Comment: I think you'll need VBA for this. IMO, well documented VBA code is much easier to read and maintain than macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Form is opened in Access as a sub form, if the `SourceObject` of a `SubForm` Control is set to it, and the parent form is loaded. So there is actually no such a thing as *opening* or *closing* a sub form.
Use [SetProperty Macro Action](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SetProperty-Macro-Action-a8ecea05-afbb-4234-a007-42dd131a2559) to either set SubForm's [`IsVisible` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823059.aspx), or it's [SourceObject Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822769.aspx).
You could also use a [Tab Control](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-tabbed-form-6869DEE9-3AB7-4F3D-8E65-3A84183C9815).